# How to call a .db file with Intel XDK?

Tags: database, html, intel

Example :

1. I created a database using SQLite
2. I export the database .db format
3. Then I save the database files in the www folder on Intel XDK
4. How to call the database ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this article on intel's official documentation that relates to what you are attempting to do: [HTML5 Local Storage](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/html5-local-storage). This article may not relate directly to SQLite databases but appears to be Intel's solution to databases within Intel XDK. In order to select from a table you would use this javascript code snippet:

```js
 function selRows() {      

       var q = "select * from myTable"; 

     db.transaction(function (t) { 
         t.executeSql(q, null, function (t, data) { 
             var html = "<table><tr><td>ID</td><td>Name</td><td>Age</td></tr>"; 

             for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
                   html += "<tr><td>" +
                   data.rows.item(i).id + "</td><td>" +
                   data.rows.item(i).name + "</td><td>" +
                   data.rows.item(i).age + "</td></tr>";
             } 

             html += "</table>";
             var el = document.getElementById("main");
             el.innerHTML = html;
         });
     });
 }
```